# How to test sample TCP Socket program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a sample TCP client and server application that I want to run but I am not sure how to run them. It says I need to compile the client program in one host and the server application in another but I have no idea how to do this when I just have one computer. I know this is very simple but I need a little help to get me started.

Here is the sample TCP Server application:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
{ 
  String clientSentence; 
  String capitalizedSentence;

  ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6790); 

  while(true) { 

               Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

       BufferedReader inFromClient = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

       DataOutputStream  outToClient = 
         new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

       clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

       capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';

       outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence); 
    } 
} 
}
```

Here is the sample TCPClient application

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
    { 
        String sentence; 
        String modifiedSentence;

        BufferedReader inFromUser = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.1.2", 6790);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = 
          new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader inFromServer = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();

        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);

        clientSocket.close(); 
                   
    } 
}
```

Is something off here?

Here is exactly what I do

[image: step1]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](https://img.skitch.com/20120715-dkwj4g28hkint1axtq4j79pm84.jpg))</sub>

[image: step2]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](https://img.skitch.com/20120715-q5a3du7hfh2eshwai37yhajymj.jpg))</sub>

This is the first time I use Eclipse so I could be doing something wrong there. I normally use DrJava but that didn't let me run both at the same time for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost any socket program can run both halves on the *same* computer. Just run the server in one window, the client in another, and specify the connection address 127.0.0.1 (which means `localhost`, your own computer).

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then because when I do that nothing happens. If I run The server application and then the client application it just stands there....

Comment: Sorry, I can't help debug your program when you just say "nothing happens". When in doubt, print more out.

Comment: I updated my post with the code. When I run the TCPServer program now I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)

Comment: You're trying to connecto to 10.0.1.2. Unless that is the actual IP address of your own computer, you'll need to change that to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Do you have a software firewall installed? Usually, firewall type programs will block incoming connections to your computer.

Comment: I have a mac but my firewall is turned off

Comment: Wait, you said above that you get that "Connection refused" error when running your TCPServer program. I would have expected that kind of error when running the TCPClient program (that error doesn't make sense for a server). Can you confirm that you stated the correct error above?

Comment: You are right. I got that error when I ran the client without running the server.

Comment: I added screenshots to the original post.

Comment: It looks like you're probably using *one* instance of Eclipse. I don't think Eclipse will run two programs at once. Either start two instances of Eclipse and run the server in one and the client in the other, or learn how to run Java programs from Terminal directly. It's easy to open multiple Terminal windows to run multiple programs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using this code, I just stepped through the program and see that the connection is established successfully (if you change to the appropriate IP such as 'localhost'). However both the TCPServer and the TCPClient do a readLine first so they are both stuck waiting for input which never comes. Change one of them to write something first.